# Vulkan: Separate vertex buffers or dynamic vertex buffers?

Tags: c++, vulkan

So I'm starting to learn Vulkan, and I still haven't done anything with multiple objects yet, thing is, if I'm making a game engine, and I'm implementing some kind of "drag and drop" thing, where you drag, for example, a cube from a panel, and drop it into the scene, is it better to... ?

- Have separate vertex buffers.
- Have just one, and make it grow kinda like a `std::vector` class or something, but this sounds really slow considering I have to perform a transfer operation with command buffers every time a resize needs to happen (every time a new object gets added to the scene).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A growing vertex buffer is usually the way to go, keep in mind Vulkan has very limited buffer handles of every type and is designed for sub-allocation (like in old school C). Excerpt from [NVIDIA's Vulkan recommendations](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/vulkan-dos-donts/):

> Use memory sub-allocation. vkAllocateMemory() is an expensive operation on the CPU. Cost can be reduced by suballocating from a large memory object. Memory is allocated in pages which have a fixed size; sub-allocation helps to decrease the memory footprint.

The only note here is to aggressively allocate your buffer as large as you believe it will grow. The other point on that page warns you against pushing the memory to its limits, the OS will give up and kill your program if you fail this:

> When memory is over-committed on Windows, the OS may temporarily suspend a process from the GPU runlist in order to page out its allocations to make room for a different process’ allocations. There is no OS memory manager on Linux that mitigates over-commitment by automatically performing paging operations on memory objects.

Comment: Since I haven't been exposed to any large scale engine, how do the big ones like Unreal do it? Do they allocate like 1GB of VRAM at the start of the program and leave it unused or how does this go?

Comment: Nothing that drastic, you generally know exactly what you're drawing, so you can allocate exactly how much memory you need.